# Django rest framework serialization on foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a django model as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class c(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='modelA')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='modelB')
```

and i have serializers as follows:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A

class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = C

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modelB = CSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = B
```

The B serializer works as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "modelB": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "b": 2,
                "a": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What do i have to tweak to make it result as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "modelB": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "b": 2,
                "a": [
                     {
                         "id": 1,
                         "comments": "",
                     }
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **CSerializer** as follows:

```
class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = C
```

Comment: but this is a foreign key relation which is the same what i am already doing. I am trying the reverse relation in the second one

Comment: @RogerFederer Have you tested my code? It produces the result what you showed as required output in your question.

Comment: oh i am so sorry! i forgot to remove the many=True, and read_only....it is working...thank you

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)